# Question about Dimension

Tags: vector-spaces

Suppose that $A$ is the space of all symmetric $n \times n$ matrices with complex entries.

I want to find the dimension of $A$.

I know that the if the entries were real, the dimension is $ \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$... but the complex thing threw me off.... Any help?

Comment: Conceivably if you want complex entries for $A$, then instead of symmetric $n\times n$ matrices you will want [Hermitian matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix).  That actually introduces an interesting wrinkle, as the "space" is not one over the complex field, but only over the real numbers (we cannot multiply a Hermitian matrix by $i$ and get a Hermitian matrix).  The dimension of Hermitian matrices as a real vector space is $n^2$, a fact noted in [the Wikipedia article just linked](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix#Properties).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the dimension on $\mathbb{C}$, it is the same for the same reason.

If you want the dimension on $\mathbb{R}$ it is $2.\frac{n(n+1)}2$ because if you have a $\mathbb{C}-$basis $\left(e_1,\cdots,e_{\frac{n(n+1)}2}\right)$, a $\mathbb{R}$-basis is for example $\left(e_1, i.e_1 ,\cdots,e_{\frac{n(n+1)}2}, i.e_{\frac{n(n+1)}2}\right)$ which has $n(n+1)$ vectors.

Answer (score 2):

Over $\mathbb C$, your the dimension will still be $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, you can even use the same basis.